# Conversion of SSL certificate from .pfx to .key

Tags: ssl, openssl, nodes, format-conversion

What is the use of **-nodes** in the command to convert .pfx to .pem?

Can I use

```
openssl pkcs12 -in keyStore.pfx -out keyStore.key -nodes
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

Per the [OpenSSL documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Pkcs12(1)) :

**-nodes : don't encrypt the private keys at all.**

Yes, you can use this command but what are you trying to do ? From the title, I'm understanding that you want to convert a certificate from pfx to pem format, is that right ?